# Send Mediator Ignores HTTP Request Data (Only sends headers!)

Tags: rest, api, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I'm creating essentially a RESTful pass through proxy for a WSO2 Data Services Server resource.

I'd like to send the following request to the ESB...

```
PUT /crm/contacts/267
```

... With the data...

```
<contacts>
<firstname>John</firstname>
</contacts>
```

... so that contact 267's first name is updated.

I use a script mediator to get the ID of the contact and add it to the XML request in the mediation flow of the InSequence (as this is how Data Services Server needs it to be formated). I then attempt to send on the request to Data Services Server using a HTTP end point.

Here is my API configuration as a reference:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="CRM" context="/crm">
   <resource methods="PUT" uri-template="/contacts/{cid}">
      <inSequence>
         <script language="js"><![CDATA[ var request= mc.getPayloadXML(); var id = mc.getProperty('uri.var.cid'); var child = <id>{id}</id>; request.appendChild(child);mc.setPayloadXML(request); ]]></script>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2"/>
         <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
         <send>
           <endpoint>
              <http method="put" uri-template="http://requestb.in/1h6werc1" />
           </endpoint>
         </send>
         <log level="full" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

**Note: that the endpoint specified here isn't my DSS endpoint, it's just a request bin I'm using to test the output of the API.**

*So the main issue here is that when I check Request Bin I'm receiving the request but there is no request body. If I change the request bin URL to the DSS endpoint, the data source is not updated. I can update the data source using the DSS resource directly, so that's working fine.*

If there's pointers you can give me to get this working that would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Strainy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried it in ESB 4.8.1 using NIO http transport.

I've used SOAP UI to send a request to this API :

[image: soapui conf]

I've used TCPMON Between the ESB and my endpoint and here is the request sent by the ESB :

```
PUT /MockJSP.jsp HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Host: 127.0.0.1:8087
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Synapse-HttpComponents-NIO

3e
<contacts>
<firstname>John</firstname>
<id>267</id></contacts>
0
```

XML data are sent, I can't see any problem : try to use tcpmon (see ESB_HOME/bin) between your ESB instance and your host "requestb.in" ?

Comment: Are the NIO transports (which I'm assuming are valid for HTTP and HTTPS?) enabled as standard? Not sure how to tell if I'm using it.

Comment: in standard, WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 use PassThrough transport. To enable NIO, rename repository/conf/axis2/axis2_nhttp.xml to repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml. I just wanted to point out that I was using NIO, but I don't know if that will change anything

Comment: Thanks Jean-Michel.

Switched the transport from PassThrough to NIO, everything's working fine now.

Could you tell me anything (or direct me to some information) about the difference between the transports? What impact might it have on the ESB?

Comment: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/ESB+Transports   AND    http://techfeast-hiranya.blogspot.fr/2013/02/how-worlds-fastest-esb-was-made.html   Pass-through looks better/faster, but I've had a lot of problems with it. NIO works fine. I'll have a look to pass-through in release 4.9.0 of WSO2 ESB